# How to count with grep or awk, pattern if it occurred x times respectively (one after the other)

Tags: count, awk, grep, design-patterns

I need help with little code. What I need is "if statement" code the counts with grep or other command how many times repeat respectively two words in the file.
The contest of file is:

```
2011/05/04 21:47:37 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - CHANNEL 1 (0,8W) (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:47:46 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:0000 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:48:11 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL
2011/05/04 21:48:21 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:48:42 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:1000 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:49:19 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:49:30 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL CHANNEL (0,8
2011/05/04 21:49:32 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:50:01 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:50:18 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:0333 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:50:21 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:0333 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:51:06 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:51:08 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:51:18 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL
2011/05/04 21:52:19 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:52:45 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:53:56 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:53:58 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:01 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:04 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:07 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:10 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:13 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:15 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:18 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2011 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:20 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2763 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0.8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:29 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
```

If words (pattern) "not found" repeat in each line one after one (like in sample file) and if it reach 10 times, then DO SOMETHING (I will put my command)

Is there any posibility that this part of code monitoring in real time current file??
I mean if start it once with crond to continuously monitoring my file?

***EDIT***
Now I see that I need something more in script than if else..
How to implement to my script watching all time (realtime) last 10 line from file?

Thx for help!

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
#!/bin/bash

while ${cleanLogFile:-true} ; do
   if (( $(grep -c "not found" logFile) > 9 )) ; then
       echo "Too many 'not found's in logFile"
       # do your stuff here
       cleanLogFile=false
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi..Thx for help.
Code is working..but if I run it like you wrote, the it give me a error: line 46: syntax error: unexpected end of file
But if I put to end of file command done, it works without error but script execute only once and it stops...there is no monitoring current file!

Comment: Now I see that I need something more in script than if else..
How to implement to my script watching all time (realtime) last 10 line from file?

Answer (score 1):

This AWK code prints out the message if and only if there are 10 or more consecutive lines with "not found":

```
! /not found/ {
    if (count >= 10) {
        print "More than 10 lines found"
    }
    count = 0
}
/not found/ {
    ++count
}

END {
    if (count >= 10) {
        print "More than 10 lines found"
    }
```

Comment: Where to implement in wich file to search "not found" words?
btw:Thx for code and support!

Comment: Now I see that I need something more in script than if else..
How to implement to my script watching all time (realtime) last 10 line from file?