# How to count with grep or awk, pattern if it occurred x times respectively (one after the other) in last 10 lines of file

Tags: count, awk, grep

I need help with little code. What I need is "if statement" code the counts with grep or other command how many times repeat respectively two words in the file.
The contest of file is:

```
2011/05/04 21:47:37 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - CHANNEL 1 (0,8W) (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:47:46 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:0000 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:48:11 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL
2011/05/04 21:48:21 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:48:42 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:1000 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:49:19 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:49:30 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL CHANNEL (0,8
2011/05/04 21:49:32 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:50:01 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:50:18 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:0333 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:50:21 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): invalid (0 ms) (of 0 avail 0) - 0000:0333 unknown (invalid SID)
2011/05/04 21:51:06 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:51:08 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:51:18 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL
2011/05/04 21:52:19 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:52:45 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:53:56 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:53:58 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:01 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:04 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:07 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:10 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2010 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:13 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2009 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:15 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2007 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:18 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2011 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:20 45992299 c blabla (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2763 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0.8W)
2011/05/04 21:54:29 05002299 c blabla2 (xxx/xxx/xx:xxx): not found (2008 ms) by blablabla (of 1 avail 1) - CHANNEL (0,8W)
```

If words (pattern) "not found" repeat in each line one after one (like in sample file) and if it reach 10 times, **but it is a last 10 line in moment when accessing the log file** then DO SOMETHING (I will put my command)

Is there any posibility that this part of code monitoring in real time current file??
I mean if start it once with crond to continuously monitoring my file?

Thx for help!

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892345/how-to-count-with-grep-or-awk-pattern-if-it-occurred-x-times-respectively-one-a

Comment: see the note that @belisarius left you on your other question linked above. Time to start awarding points to those people that spend their time helping you solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tail -n 10 -f <filename> | grep -c "not found"
```

That should give you the count of lines in the last 10 lines of the file that contain not found.  You could then set it up to run at timed intervals and do whatever you want if the count is what you are looking for.

Comment: thx..but how to make it to run all the time and monitor the file in realtime?

Comment: add an entry in the crontab to excute the shell script you create to do what you want every minute. crontab only fires once a minute at most so if you need actual 'REAL TIME' monitoring you may need to do something different, for instance having your script start running in the background on startup and put the code in your script in a loop that fires as often as you need.  a crontab entry might look something like this:   0-59 * * * * /the/path/to/your/script.sh

Comment: Hi! I tried it but it not worked.
When I start script it do nothing and I must ctrl+z to force stop.Why?

Comment: drop the -f option from tail, I forgot that that continues to look at incoming lines from the file so it will not return properly in your scenario.

Comment: Yes now working..
But, can you tell me what does it mean return value 1?
Is this value like TRUE or it find a 10 line "with not" found pattern?
Thx for helping me!

Comment: I will assume at this point that you have entered the command string exactly as I have shown above.  Without seeing your code, I have to work off of assumptions.  So, here is a quick rundown of what the command does.  First, the "tail" command gets x-number of lines from the bottom of the specified file.  We then "pipe" the results of tail to the grep command and give it the argument of -c which tells grep to only provide a count of the lines in the input that match the query string provided.  So my assumption is that only 1 line matched on that call.

Comment: If you have more to your script, the 1 could be the last return value or could represent true that the code executed without error.  To see a help screen on unix shell commands you can type "man <command name>" in a shell and you will find a wealth of information on what is done and what the options are.  Also, do not forget to upvote helpful information and select an answer if your questions is answered.  It will make others more willing to help if you reward the help.

Comment: Yes..thx for helping me..I made a script and its working perfectly..
I put this in if-else statemenat and now is OK.
Oce again..thx for help!